# Rda objects and reactivity in Shiny, R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a graph that should be updated by a dateInput in shiny. However, my app requires data to be loaded at the start. This messes with reactivity, and ensures that my graph cannot be updated, here is my script that works:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  #For Date of Update, days of unemployment
  dateInput("updatedate", "Select Date", value = "2015-06-01", min = "2015-05-20", max = "2015-07-13", format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0, language = "en"),
  ggvisOutput("duration")
)


server <- function(input, output) {

Durationdata<-reactive({
  selectedupdate<-with(zoomlastupdate, zoomlastupdate[(Lastupdate == as.Date(input$updatedate, '%Y-%m-%d')),])
  selectedupdate<-with(selectedupdate, selectedupdate[(Unemployed == 1),])
  selectedupdate<-na.omit(selectedupdate)
  count1<- selectedupdate[,1:2]
  tabcount1<- data.frame(Duration=count(count1, 'spell')[,1], Unemployed=count(count1, 'spell')[,2])
  tabcount1
  })

all_values <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  paste0(c("Duration","Unemployed"), ": ", format(x)[c(1,3)], collapse = "<br />")
}

add_title <- function(vis, ..., x_lab = "X units",y_lab="Y units", title = "Plot Title") 
{
  add_axis(vis, "x", title = x_lab) %>% 
    add_axis("x", orient = "top", ticks = 0, title = title,
             properties = axis_props(
               axis = list(stroke = "white"),
               labels = list(fontSize = 0)
             ), ...) %>% add_axis("y", title=y_lab)

}

Durationdata %>% ggvis(x=~Duration, y =~Unemployed, fill := "#fff8dc") %>% layer_bars(width=0.5) %>% add_tooltip(all_values, "hover") %>% add_title(title = "Unemployment Duration", x_lab="Duration of Unemployment (Months)", y_lab="Number of Unemployed Persons") %>% set_options(width = 1000, height = 600, keep_aspect = NULL, resizable = TRUE) %>% bind_shiny("duration")


}
```

when I put the following code on top of it:

```
load("lastupdateemp.Rda")
load("zoomlastupdate.Rda")
load("lastupdateworkexp.Rda")
```

The reactive graph fails to update with the data input. How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: When you are using reactive functions, you must include session object in your server function. `server <- function(input,output,session)`